# How to run Jquery after DOM is loaded in Angular Js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have created a single page application (multiple) views using angular that loads different page content. I would like apply initial focus for the first input element for all the screens throughout using angular script rather than using autofocus attribute in each and every page form element.

Is there any way to do this?

and

How do we know whether Angular view (DOM) is completely loaded or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MainCtrl you can listen the event when angular view is loaded.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', function($scope) {

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      $('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible:first').focus();
    });

  })

.controller('childController', function($scope) {
  
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div>
      <div ng-controller="childController">
        <form name="myForm" id="myForm">
          <label>Field1</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="first" ng-required="true" />
          <br>
          <label>Field2</label>
          <input type="text" ng-model="second" ng-required="is_mobile" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Gaurav.  In the example, we have only one main controller but when we load multiple views in main ctrl, will the focus work for all the views.  Or do we need to write document ready in all the child controllers?

Comment: @klmuralimohan you need to write it only in parent controller and it will find the first input element of first form in the view and focuses it.updated my answer according to your need.

Comment: I have tried this for partial views but it is not working... Is anything wrong my code. Here the example http://fiddle.jshell.net/95wEL/42/

Comment: @klmuralimohan glad I could help :-)